# Не срабатывает бинд в usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, usercontrol

Почему у меня программа не хочет находить "Design"?

Код лежащий в usercontrol :

```
namespace MySoft
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для designform.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public class Design
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class designform: UserControl
    {
     // Ну и так далее...
```

Xaml лежащий в usercontrol :

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySoft.designform"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySoft"

             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="245">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:Design x:Name="asd" Color="#FF19D3A8" description="asd" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- И так далее... -->
```

**Ошибки** :

> Имя "Design" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:MySoft".
>
> Каждая запись словаря должна иметь сопоставленный ключ.
>
> Имя "background" не существует в текущем контексте.

Comment: Что значит «не хочет»? Что конкретно происходит не так? Опишите.

Comment: @VladD тему обновил

Comment: Странно. Попробуйте rebuild, а?

Comment: @VladD, не, на них как раз всё останавливается (

Comment: А вы уверены, что это не ошибка Intellisense? И есть ли **другие** ошибки? Например, что за проблема с background? (Есть шанс, что стоит сначала поправить именно её!)

Comment: Ну с background я проблему решил, осталось 2 ошибки =)

Comment: А, тьфу. Ну так укажите `x:Key` для вашего `local:Design`. Оно ж вам и пишет, что ключа нет.

Comment: @VladD Последняя ошибка осталась ))

Comment: Всё та же? А если теперь сделать rebuild? И дайте, пожалуйста, точную ошибку из окна Output.

Comment: @VladD в смысле перестроить?

Comment: Build -> Rebuild Solution

Comment: Всё, заработало, но всё таки "Перестроить решение" у меня :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня точно такая же проблема с WpfControlToolkit.
Студия и встроенный дизайнер упорно не хотят смотреть в ссылку, но при ребилде все работает, хотя и без предпросмотра в дизайнере)